# Locating element by css in internet explorer for selenium-webdriver using python

Tags: html, css, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I want to locate an element by css in internet explorer for this particular set of tags.

```
<header class="panel-heading" id="uploadSupply">
 <form action="/emapweb/OPSReport/UploadSupplyData" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <input name="file" id="fileUploadSupply" style="float: left;" type="file">
   **<button class="btn btn-grp btn-primary btn-shadow" id="btnUploadSupply" type="button">**
    <div class="tooltips" data-original-title="Upload Supply Dump Data" data-placement="bottom">
     <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
       Upload Supply Dump Data
    </div>
   </button>
 </form>
</header>
```

In the above HTML tags I'd I want to locate the element button(4th line) which I've highlighted by using CSS Selector method.

I've already tried using chrome and it works but I need to use IE only. 
The css selector in chrome is by using **#btnUploadSupply > div**

Could someone help me out, please?

Comment: `button` can not contain `div`, that is invalid HTML. Might be that browser error correction creates a different DOM.

Comment: But this is a working HTML page. 
Please pardon me but I am naive on this.